# InfluxDB Flux - Filter where field matches value

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I'm using [InfluxDB](https://influxdata.com/products/influxdb-overview) with [Grafana](https://grafana.com), and I have a measurement called `items` with some tags and a field called `itemType`. I need to filter for rows where `itemType` is a certain string. The following InfluxQL query does exactly what I need:

```
SELECT * FROM "items" WHERE "itemType" = 'example'
```

How can I do the same in [Flux](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/get-started)?

I currently have the following query which does everything except filter by field:

```
from(bucket: "dbname/autogen")
    |> range(start: 2020-10-12T01:56:34Z, stop: 2020-10-12T02:54:10Z)
    |> filter(fn:(r) => r._measurement == "items")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 5m, fn: count)
```

But replacing the `filter` function with `filter(fn:(r) => r._measurement == "items" and r.itemType == "example")` returns no results, even though the InfluxQL query above does return data when used in the InfluxDB CLI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your specified flux query would work if **itemType** was a tag, however, since it is a field one of the ways to make the query work is by setting conditions on the field name and its value as follows:

```
from(bucket: "dbname/autogen")
    |> range(start: 2020-10-12T01:56:34Z, stop: 2020-10-12T02:54:10Z)
    |> filter(fn:(r) => r._measurement == "items" and r._field == "itemType" and r._value == "example")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 5m, fn: count)
```

Comment: how does it work if u want to cumulate 2 filters on 2 fields ?
The same as "where criteria1=value1 and criteria2=value2" ?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit surprised that this has not been answered in more than three years as it popped up several times while I was researching this. If I understand the question correctly, then the problem is based on a misunderstanding of how data is structured in InfluxDB and the accepted answer ignores that the question aims at retrieving not just the count of matching items but other columns that belong to the filtered "rows" (`SELECT * FROM ...`).

## Columnar format

InfluxDB is not a traditional relational database. Your request does not return a table like an Excel sheet with one column for each field and field names as their headers, but literally a column that contains the field names.

Example:

| _time | _field | _value | (...and a few more taht do not matter here) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:10 | "fruit" | "apple" |  |
| 00:10 | "color" | "red" |  |
| 00:20 | "fruit" | "apple" |  |
| 00:20 | "color" | "green" |  |
| 00:30 | "fruit" | "banana" |  |
| 00:30 | "color" | "yellow" |  |
| 00:40 | "fruit" | "banana" |  |
| 00:40 | "color" | "brown" |  |

Let's say you want to retrieve the color of all apples with a query like `SELECT * FROM something WHERE fruit = "apple"`, right?

If you filter with `r._field == "fruit" and r._value == "apple"` (as suggested by the accepted answer) you will only retrieve two lines:

| _time | _field | _value | (...and a few more taht do not matter here) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:10 | "fruit" | "apple" |  |
| 00:20 | "fruit" | "apple" |  |

In particular, you will lose all other fields except the one you are filtering.

## Row format

What you want is your related data being structured in a row, which you probably know from a relational database like MySQL. You want this:

| _time | fruit | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:10 | apple | red |
| 00:20 | apple | green |
| 00:30 | banana | yellow |
| 00:40 | banana | brown |

If you filter this with `r.fruit == "apple"` you get all the data that belongs to the value you are filtering for:

| _time | fruit | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:10 | apple | red |
| 00:20 | apple | green |

## pivot()

In order to convert your columnar data in influxdb to row data you can use the command [`pivot()`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/pivot/?_gl=1*y4x05f*_ga*MTI4MjQ5NzU3My4xNzA1NjY5ODg0*_ga_CNWQ54SDD8*MTcwNTk1NzgzMi4zLjEuMTcwNTk1Nzk0My4yNC4wLjA.).

It takes three arguments:

- The key that should be grouped into rows (in my example `_time`)
- The key that should be grouped into columns (i.e. the headings or keys of your new table, this is usually `_field`)
- The key that contains the values (most of the time `_value`)

So, putting it all together...

## tl;dr

The equivalent to `SELECT * FROM something WHERE fruit = "apple"` in flux is

```
from(bucket: "mybucket")
    |> range(start: 2020-10-12T01:56:34Z, stop: 2020-10-12T02:54:10Z)
    |> filter(fn:(r) => r._measurement == "something")
    |> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
    |> filter(fn:(r) => r.fruit == "apple")
```

(Technically it is not entirely equivalent because of the mandatory range.)

Oh, and if you want to aggregate this, you should do it before the pivot as pretty much everything else expects the columnar format.